# Setting up Qyoto in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, qt, qyoto

I’m trying to develop an application using Qyoto with Visual Studio,but I’m having trouble setting up the IDE.I have downloaded the binary package for windows, but I could not find any documents on how to setup the IDE(Visual Studio / Mono Develop) to use qyoto.

Any links or tutorials would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There exists an example (not checked out by me). A couple of dlls were integrated within his/her solution.

[integrating dlls](https://bitbucket.org/dzmuh/qyoto.examples/src/1aebe51206d555dc2f27456509b688917ef74f3f/Lib?at=master)

[Bitbucket example](https://bitbucket.org/dzmuh/qyoto.examples/src/1aebe51206d5?at=master)